# How to embed a vertex into another

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I'm new to OrientDB. I would to know (if is possbile) how to obtain with a `select` or a `match` (or other) the following result:

I have an `Activity` vertex, with an outgoing `Has` edge to a `User` vertex.

`Activity -Has-> User`

```json
// Activity Vertex
{
  "@rid": "#28:0",
  "field_values": {
    "a3b4n": "Foo"
  }
}
```

```json
// Has Edge
{
  "@rid": "#34:0",
    "field_id": "c7d4j"
}
```

```json
// User Vertex
{
  "@rid": "#29:0",
  "field_values": {
    "v7d4j": "Bar"
  }
}
```

I would to get the edge field `field_id` value and put it into the activity `field_values` object with the value of the entire User vertex (not the reference).

The result:

```json
// Activity Vertex
{
  "@rid": "#28:0",
  "field_values": {
    "a3b4n": "Foo",
    "c7d4j": {
      "@rid": "#29:0",
      "field_values": {
        "v7d4j": "Bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested projections:

```
 SELECT a3b4n, out("Has"):{*} as c7d4j FROM Activity WHERE ...
```

For reference https://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/sql/SQL-Projections.html#nested-projections